# Elements.xml and external files

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2013

I have a SharePoint app with a Module added.
The `Elements.xml` has the following line:

```
<File Path="AppAssets\Icon.png" Url="SPAssets/Icon.png">
```

I know that the Path is the local path and the Url is where they will be deployed.

Is it possible to store the files in a SharePoint site and point to them in the xml file. Then I can update the `icon.png` whenever I need to. I've tried and this does not work...

```
<File Path="https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/site/list/Icon.png" Url="SPAssets/Icon.png">
```

Comment: The modules purpose is only to provision the file, and do so in the scope of where the feature is activated. I fail to see how what you are trying to do makes sense with that in mind. I mean, if the file already exists elsewhere (and the user can access it) why not use it from where it already is?